# how does C know certain code is executable (pointers to functions specifically)?

Tags: c

Suppose you have a pointer to a function: `void(*ptf)(void* arg1, void* arg2);`

When you later invoke ptf with parentheses `ptf(arg1, arg2);` how does the program know it is executable? What I mean is it's just a pointer to a memory address. It could mean anything. How does it know it's a function, not some other data? Is it due to some meta-data located on the stack? Or are there certain key characters that tell it so, comparable to how an array terminates in '\0' and even how DNA has special beginning and ending sequences I think.

Comment: 'C' doesn't know, and there's nothing stopping someone from making this bug.

Comment: Then how does it run?

Comment: *Then how does it run?*  The next instruction will jump to that address.... if it is executable code, it will work fine.  If it happens to be an `int-ptr`, or other inappropriate type, the program will exhibit Undefined Behavior, and likely crash (but could result in Nasal Demons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call something as a function, you are telling C it is an executable function.

The grammar for a function call is an expression (technically a *postfix-expression*) followed by a (possibly empty) argument list in parentheses. Because of the structure of the C grammar, the compiler can distinguish these parentheses marking a function call from other uses of parentheses.

Additionally, that expression must have a pointer-to-function type, and the compiler must issue a diagnostic if it is not such a type. You can force the type with a cast, and then you are responsible for the consequences of lying to the compiler. (If the expression is a function designator, such as a function name, it is automatically converted to a pointer to that function.)

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes a lot of sense. So it was neither of my guesses above, but just the fact you're using parenthesis in a certain way. Therefore, you could technically try to invoke an 'int' or any data type. Worst case it will just give you a compiler error. However, there are certain security considerations surrounding this aspect of invocation, as well as certain safeguards to mitigate them on different systems. Have I stated it correctly?

Comment: @gcr: I expect most compilers would give you an error when calling with an expression that is not a pointer-to-function type, but the C standard only requires a “diagnostic message,” so it could be just a warning. There are security concerns about executing things that are not code or jumping to places in code that were not planned, but these do not often arise from misuse of function calls. More commonly, a mistaken design in a program allows a malicious party to cause a buffer overflow that puts data on the stack where not intended, and that can overwrite a return address, and then…

Comment: … returning from a function will jump to a place controlled by that malicious party, as one example.

Comment: Actually I did some playing around:   int* x = phw;
  printf("phw function address: %p, a clone of it %p and its invocation %d\n", phw, x, phw()); Works as expected. phw is a function that prints hello world and returns 1. phw == x, but when I try to invoke x, x(), I don't even get a warning but an error: "called object ‘x’ is not a function or function pointer" Trying to cast this pointer to function pointer just for learning purposes. In my head it should work bc its same memory adds but it doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: The program does not know that. The compiler may know it, but not the program.

Here is a program that (on some systems) prints the classic Hello World!

```
const int main[] = {
    -443987883, 440, 113408, -1922629632,
    4149, 899584, 84869120, 15544,
    266023168, 1818576901, 1461743468, 1684828783,
    -1017312735
};
```

Note that `main` is not a function, and when it's compiled you're getting told that:

```
$ gcc -Wall final_array.c -o sixth
final_array.c:1:11: warning: ‘main’ is usually a function [-Wmain]
 const int main[] = {
           ^
```

So what's happening here is that `main` is just an `int` array, and it's filled with binary data that corresponds to certain assembly code. You can read more about it here. It's very interesting. https://jroweboy.github.io/c/asm/2015/01/26/when-is-main-not-a-function.html

Comment: Cool. I'm interested in getting more into assembly later. I tried running it in C. It compiled with no problem but got a seg fault when ran. I'll file this info away for later. Cool to know how things really work. I am always asking the question "but how is it implemented"

Answer (score 1):

The comment provided by @jwimberley is correct, however a compiler and operating system (combination) may take advantage of particular hardware features.  On Intel processors, for instance, there is a security feature called the Executable Disable Bit (EDB).  When data is stored on a page with that bit set will not be executable.